# Custom field does not save data in db

Tags: 8, entities

I created a custom field because i wanted to store a multiple field with:

- social type (Facebook, Twitter, etc..)
- social ID

Everything shows fine, but when I save some data, nothing is saved and no errors are triggered.

The table is in the database and it's completed with all columns, but no data inside

The "isEmpty" function does not get values at all, what am I missing?

Here is the field code

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\magicnet\Plugin\Field\FieldType\Social.
 */

namespace Drupal\magicnet\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'social' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType (
 *   id = "social",
 *   label = @Translation("Social"),
 *   description = @Translation("Immagazzina tipo di social e ID social"),
 *   default_widget = "social_widget",
 *   default_formatter = "social_formatter"
 * )
 */
class Social extends FieldItemBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return array(
      'columns' => array(
        'social_type' => array(
          'description' => 'Social',
          'type' => 'int',
          'length' => 5,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'social_id' => array(
          'description' => 'ID del social',
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 255,
          'not null' => FALSE,

        )
      ),
    );
  }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isEmpty() {
        $value1 = $this->get('social_type')->getValue();
        $value2 = $this->get('social_id')->getValue();
        return empty($value1) || empty($value2);
    }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    // Add our properties.
    $properties['social_type'] = DataDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('Seleziona il social'));

    $properties['social_id'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('ID del social'));



    return $properties;
  }
}
```

The Widget code

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\magicnet\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\SocialWidget.
 */

namespace Drupal\magicnet\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'social' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget (
 *   id = "social_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("Social widget"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "social"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class SocialWidget extends WidgetBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('social');
    $termini=array();
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $termini[$term->tid]=$term->name;
    }

    $element['social_type'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Social'),
      '#options' => $termini
    );
    $element['social_id'] = array(
      '#type' => 'number',
      '#title' => $this->t('Social ID'),
      '#size' => 80
    );


    $element += [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
    ];

    return array('value' => $element);
  }
}
```

Formatter code

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\magicnet\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\SocialFormatter.
 */

namespace Drupal\magicnet\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'social' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter (
 *   id = "social_formatter",
 *   label = @Translation("Social"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "social"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class SocialFormatter extends FormatterBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode = NULL) {
    $elements = array();

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $markup = 'Type:'.$item->social_type.', id:'.$item->social_id;

      $elements[$delta] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $markup,
      );
    }

    return $elements;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any luck with this ?

Comment: I move on to another solution, but i think the problem is about the definition of the data kind, something does not match so it does not save